# Probability- Calculate: $P(A' \cap ( A \cup B) )$

Tags: probability

I am stuck on a homework question and I don't know how to approach this. Please help! The question is as follows:

"Let $A$ and $B$ be two events.

$P(A)= 0.3$
$P(B)= 0.4$
$P(A\cap B)= 0.2$

Denote the complement of $A$ by $A'$. Then $P(A'\cap(A\cup B))$ is closest to?

a.) 0.1      b.)0.2     c.) 0.3     d.) 0.4

(The correct answer is 0.2, but I don't get how they got it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as in logic you have that $A'(A+B)=A'B$, in set theory you have that $A'\cap(A\cup B)=A'\cap B$

And I assume you can find $P(A'\cap B)$ yourself

Comment: oh so whenever there is A' ∩ (A U/∩ B), it becomes (A' ∩/U B)?

Comment: @farooq1219 Not sure what you meant by the $\cap / \cup$ ... and you do have to be careful there. We have $A'\cap(A\cup B)=A'\cap B$, but $A'\cap(A\cap B)=(A'\cap A)\cap B=\emptyset \cap B = \emptyset$ ... which is not $A' \cap B$

Comment: Do you know where i can learn more about this topic? to better understand the properties of the complement?

Comment: @farooq1219 Look up 'Boolean Algebra laws'.  This is for logic ... but you have exactly isomorph laws for sets.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $P(A'\cap(A\cup B))$ represents the probability that $A$ doesn't happen and also that either $A$ or $B$ happens.  How can you simplify that statement?